# MYSQL Case statement issue when join table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables called `history` and `updates`. If need to update History table values, then updated values insert into update table with `Key_id`.

`Key_id` mapped with History table columns.

In here History table contains `start_date` and `close_date`. When we need to update history table particular row `start_date`, Then
Assume history table id is `243247`, and `start_date` need to update as '`2021-11-02`' then
update table id will auto generate, new_value field to '`2021-11-02`' and `Key_id` to 1

- Key_id = 1 means start_date
- key_id = 4 means close_date

Please see the below images

**History Table**

[image]

**Updates table**

[image]

**Question:**
I need to get all the records with `history` table, if update table contains values related to history table, then need to get only the latest value and only get in a single row in history table

**For an example**
history table first row to we have 5 updated values in updates table. I need to assign last updated values(both `start_date` and `close_date`) to first row in history table.

**Here is the query I have tried**

```
SELECT ch.id,  
     (CASE cu.key_id
     when  1
        then cu.new_value
        else ch.start_date
    END)AS start_date,
    
    (CASE cu.key_id
        when 4 
        then cu.new_value 
        else ch.close_date
    END)AS close_date 
    
     FROM  history ch
    LEFT JOIN  _updates  cu 
    ON ch.id = cu.history_id    
    group by ch.id
    ORDER BY cu.id  DESC;
```

My issue is, this query return only `single value` from update table. I need to get `both` updated latest values in a `single row`.
Please tell me how to resolve this issue